# Is this url "https://sfIntace.visual.force.com/apex/VFpage" is Lightning or classic

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I am new to Salesfore Lightning experience. I open vf page from tab in Lightning experience it open with some lightning URL. But when I open page from all visualforce pages screen, it show url like classic. something like this "https://sfIntace.visual.force.com/apex/VFpage".
Is this also a Lightning?

Answer (score 0):

Some example URLs from a Visualforce page I have:

- In Classic opening the page:
  https://data-speed-26-dev-ed--cve.visualforce.com/apex/PaymentCalculation
- In Lex opening a tab containing the Visualforce page from the "All Items" list:
  https://data-speed-26-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/lightning/n/cve__PaymentCalculation?0.source=aloha
- In Lex opening the page via a button:
  https://data-speed-26-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#eyJjb21wb25lbnREZWYiOiJvbmU6YWxvaGFQYWdlIiwiYXR0cmlidXRlcyI6eyJhZGRyZXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9kYXRhLXBvd2VyLTE2LWRldi1lZC5saWdodG5pbmcuZm9yY2UuY29tL2FwZXgvY3ZlX19QYXltZW50Q2FsY3VsYXRpb24%2FbWVzc2FnZUlkPW5vbmUifSwic3RhdGUiOnt9fQ%3D%3D

These URL patterns have and will probably continue to change so don't rely on them. The second and third are both rendered in the full Lightning UI: the difference is presumably that the third holds some information about the launch context that the second does not.